# What's going on with the view layout?

Tags: discussion

Over the last couple of days, the layout of the site has changed drastically and in small ways after that. What's happening? Was there an announcement? They are convenient changes, anyway, but was this supposed to be announced?

Comment: Does [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el) answer  your question?  If so, there's also an attempt to [create a userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/9293/legacyquestions-bringing-back-the-old-questions-design) to replicate the old appearance.

Comment: The new layout is great, I don't think I want to go back :)

Comment: When I noticed it suddenly changed, I instantly went over to Meta Stack Exchange to check if there was a non-sticky announcement. Personally, I think what I dislike with the new design was already highlighted in some of the posted answers (basically, I can't quickly see the meta information on the left such as votes and views without having to focus, and going from post to post on the questions list is somehow more straining now; maybe too much white space inbetween each and the text is too tiny).

Answer (score 9):

There are ongoing changes, as documented in [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el) to make all sites on the network more mobile-friendly.

As it was not well received, the community over there has requested many changes, which have been rapidly deployed. Hopefully things will settle soon.

Comment: It's currently the 4th most _negatively_ voted post on meta.se.  I think "not well received" is a bit of an understatement. :)

Comment: Idk, I like it #unpopularopinion